# Best Way to transfer file between multiple remote server(windows)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, powershell, windows-server-2012

Currently I decided to go with powershell script which creates session and then copies the file to remotes machine(Windows server). If there exists better approach to this please let me any better approach performance wise, as I have to transfer to multiple servers(may be 100). Please suggest if exists better way in other programming language(may be java, python etc)

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "username\password"
Copy-Item $source_path -Destination $destination_path -ToSession $Session
$session | Remove-Session
```

Above code it referred from [Copy-Item-Microsoft-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7).

Comment: There are plenty of tools for this. You've been able to do this long before PowerShell ever existed. PowerShell is just another one. Don't write a script if you don't have to. Windows Rocopy, already in Windows is far more performant and specifically designed for such things.    ---   [robocopy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)   ---   [Robocopy: The Ultimate Guide (A Complete How-To)](https://adamtheautomator.com/robocopy-the-ultimate/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use PowerShell to do it, you can even use robocopy in your Powershell script. There are scripts on the MS powershellgallery.com and gallery.technet.com (this Technet site is being retired and taken offline soon btw - so get what you need before it's gone.) for you to download and use and or tweak as needed.

So, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, unless you know it's really a better wheel, or it's a learning use case. Leverage what is available first and if it does not fit the need, tweak it before starting from scratch.

> [Script PowerShell Robocopy GUI Tool - PowerCopy](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Robocopy-GUI-08c9cacb)
>
> Download: PowerCopy.ps1
>
> [Script Robocopy and PowerShell - gallery.technet.microsoft.com](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Robocopy-and-PowerShell-8e3d8011)
>
> Download: Robocopy&PowerShell.ps1
>
> [Script Robocopy launching multiple concurrent sessions](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Robocopy-launching-f67faec7)
>
> Download: robocopy.zip
>
> [Script PowerShell - Robocopy launching multiple concurrent](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Robocopy-1b4e1cec)
>
> Download: SyncRobocopy.zip

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize UNC paths provided your current login has access to all the servers.

`$destinationPath = "\\$server\D$\destination\folder\"`

```bsh
# Get list of servers
$serverList = Get-Content D:\listOfServer.txt
# Source file path doesn't change
$sourcePath = "D:\source\myFile.exe"

foreach($server in $serverList) {
  # Destination UNC path changes based on server name 
  $destinationPath = "SEE ABOVE"
  # Check that full folder structure exists and create if it doesn't
  if(!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) {
    # -Force will create any intermediate folders
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationPath
  }
  # Copy the file across
  Copy-Item $sourcePath $destinationPath
}
```

Note: I've added the `$destinationPath` code example at the top, as the `\`'s cause StackOverflow markup the write the rest of the code in red string colours, which makes it very hard to read.